# How can I hide the lines between some, not all, columns in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Is it possible to hide only some of the lines separating columns in a winforms DataGridView?

`myDataGridView.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;` hides the vertical lines on the whole grid, but how can I hide specific vertical lines?

Comment: You would have to go into the CellPaint method yourself and paint which lines you want.

Comment: If you fill your datagridview with a database table, wouldn't it be easier to join those values on your select statement?

Comment: @antonio_veneroso It's from a database, but there's a custom column between two of the databound columns of type `DataGridViewImageColumn`, which is manually populated, and I want to remove the line between the icon and the text.

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView control is customizable, to the single cell.
Its customization can be a bit tricky, though.

If you want a custom cell/column format or behavior, you have to build one that overrides the internal mechanism (it's not really that complicated).

First, create a custom column/cell class, deriving from their base class and then you set your new default properties.

Since you want to show bitmaps in a DataGridView Column, lets build one:

```
public class MyCustomColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
   public MyCustomColumn()
   {
      CellTemplate = new MyCustomCell();
      //Set the .ValueType of its Cells to Bitmap
      CellTemplate.ValueType = typeof(Bitmap);
   }
}
```

Then you define the new properties of your Column Cells:
Some default properties are necessary to prevent internal errors when the
new cells are created. A default image must be initialized.

```
public class MyCustomCell : DataGridViewImageCell
{
   public MyCustomCell() : this(true) { }
      
   public MyCustomCell(bool valueIsIcon)
   {
      //Set the .ImageLayout to "Zoom", so the image will scale
      ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
      //This is the predefined image if no image is set as Value. You can set this to whatever you want.
      //Here I'm defining an invisible bitmap of 1x1 pixels
      Value = new Bitmap(1,1);
      //This is an internal switch. Doesn't mean much here. Set to true to comply with the standard.
      ValueIsIcon = valueIsIcon;
   }
      
   public override DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle AdjustCellBorderStyle(
         DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyleInput,
         DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceHolder,
         bool singleVerticalBorderAdded,
         bool singleHorizontalBorderAdded,
         bool firstVisibleColumn,
         bool firstVisibleRow)
   {
      //Set the new values for these cells borders, leaving out the right one.
      dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceHolder.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;

      dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyleInput.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
      dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceHolder.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;
      dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyleInput.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.Single;

      return dataGridViewAdvancedBorderStylePlaceHolder;
   }
}
```

In the end, you instantiate your new column and add it to the Columns collection of your DataGridView.
You can insert your custom column in any valid position inside the collection.

You can place this code in you `Form.Load` Event:

```
MyCustomColumn myColumn = new MyCustomColumn();
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, myColumn);
```

Of course you can set any other property to further customize your cells format.
.